# Java accessing a value in the client

Tags: java, server, client

I'm having problems trying to communicate between the server and the client class. 
Here is my very simple Server.java:

```
public class Server {

  public static int position = 1;

  public int getPosition() {
    return position;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    position++;
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080);
    Socket s = server.accept();
    System.out.println(position);
  }

}
```

And here is my Client:

```
public class Client {



  public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    Server serv = new Server();
    Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8080);
    System.out.println("Connected!!");
    int a = ser.getPosition();
    System.out.println(a); 
  }
}
```

So when I print the position on the Server I get 2, and when it prints in the Client it remains as 1 even though the value that is static was changed on the Server.

Please help me fix this. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What is your expectation?

Comment: This is not at all how it works. I recommend looking up a client server tutorial. Not to mention that the above code won't even compile.

Comment: Sorry.. I just re-edited it and it should compile and work now

Comment: @VPK my expectation is that when I print a in the client, I should get 2, since in the server I increment the value to 2.

Comment: Based on the two main() methods, you likely have two different programs running that don't share the same server class.  Rather than share a class, consider defining an interface for the communication across the socket.  There are lots of examples - https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077322/core-java/core-java-sockets-programming-in-java-a-tutorial.html.

Comment: You are doing multi-threaded programming. Those variables exist on different processes so the idea of 'static' doesn't apply the way you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

well, you don't communicate between the server and the client, just call the getPosition() method in server class, not by socket.
here is the [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html) and a [guide](http://www.baeldung.com/a-guide-to-java-sockets).